# webkit is not defined : InAppBrowser Cordova

Tags: android, cordova, webkit, cordova-plugins, inappbrowser

I am running an InAppBrowser instance from typescript file in Cordova application. I have the latest InAppBrowser plugin hooked in my package.json. When I add listener on loadStop event of this InAppBrowser. It doesn't execute script saying 'webkit is not defined'. I am not able to find answers related to it. Does any body know how to resolve this?

Code Snippet

```
      switchHybridApp.on("loadstop").subscribe((event: InAppBrowserEvent) => {
      console.log("Here I am 3");
      console.log('loadstop has been fired'); // this fires
      debugger;
        // when this has been executed, `webkit` variable doesn't exist inside of the `inappbrowser`
        // instance
        switchHybridApp.executeScript({ code: "\
        var message = 'this is the message';\
        var messageObj = {my_message: message};\
        var stringifiedMessageObj = JSON.stringify(messageObj);\
        webkit.messageHandlers.cordova_iab.postMessage(stringifiedMessageObj);"
      });
      }
  );
```

Error 
[image: Error]

**Solutions I tried which didn't work out**

(window as any).webkit....

( window).webkit....

Comment: What version of the inappbrowser plugin do you have installed? Note that the postMessage API functionality you're attempting to use is not present in the most recent npm release, only in `v3.1.0-dev` which must be directly installed from the Github repo - [see here](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/issues/472#issuecomment-491786494)

Comment: @DaveAlden I am pointing it to dev version only. (github link). Still not able to resolve this. I was waiting for your comment. Saw your previous answers on github.

Comment: Try building & running https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser-test as a (previously) known working reference

Comment: @DaveAlden that works. But what we do in our InAppBrowser is open an external link (web product). We use angular hence we called it in .ts file. We reach till event listner but it throws this error. also I am using ionic in app browser. for some reason I am not able to use cordova.InAppBrowser.open it says undefined. also can't use window.webkit.. there is no webkit in window !!!!

Comment: @DaveAlden that external link's .ts is not native. we just have .ts file which opens inAppbrowser , rest after all is handled by its controller (webside code not mobile). how do we detect any action on that product page to let native .ts know.

Comment: `executeScript()` works by `eval()` the code string directly in the Webview as Javascript. Hence you should be injecting Javascript not Typescript. i.e. get rid of `<any>`.

Comment: @DaveAlden I tried without any first still didn't work.

Comment: Problem was: I have a website opened in IAB. Code snippet works on native web pages loaded. But mine was hosted. So this won't have solution until you open native html file in IAB

Comment: and turns out I  was wrong after an year

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I am here after a year to answer this question and how I solved it. So I had infinite running interval to check localStorage of native and inappbrowser using executeScript, but that was a pretty bad option. Now that InAppBrowser has 'postMessage' implemented.
Its very simple communication now.

What I did is, web app I opened inside inAppBrowser, I ran this in my ts file.

```
(window as any).webkit.messageHandlers.cordova_iab.postMessage(sendToNative);
```

**note that, objToSend must be a JSON object. Passing a simple string won't work.**

you can create object something like this -

```
const sendToNative= 'frontCameraOpen';
const sendToNative= {message: sendToNative};
const stringifiedMessageObj = JSON.stringify(sendToNative);
```

Now from native side, use this eventlistner like

```
inAppBrowser.on('message').subscribe((dataFromIAB) => {
      alert(dataFromIAB.data.sendToNative);
});
```

Thanks @DaveAlden for this feature, I was doing it wrong a year ago lol.

Comment: I am stilling getting undefined for webkit in android...

Comment: @Umair if you are trying to access that on native side it will show undefined. window.webkit script has to run inside the webapp opened in inappbrowser. Also check the version, older version doesn’t have this

Answer (score 2):

Stumbled over the same issue when trying to call `postMessage` in a page load event. On iOS this works as `webkit` is already defined at that point. On Android, `webkit` is defined (injected) *after* the initial page load, so `webkit.messageHandlers.cordova_iab.postMessage` fails.

Instead of webkit, cordova_iab can be used:

```
const postMessage = (obj) => {
  const target = cordova_iab ?? webkit.messageHandlers.cordova_iab;
  target.postMessage(JSON.stringify(obj));
};
```